# Как отправить Local notifications когда приложение полностью закрыто (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, уведомления

У меня есть база данных, где хранятся товары со сроком годности. При истечении срока годности пользователю должно прийти уведомление об этом. Но эти уведомления должны приходить и в том случае, если пользователь выключил свое приложение (оно не работает даже в бекграунде). Вопрос: как это сделать? Покажите мне код, пожалуйста.
Вот мой код (AppDelegate):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in }

    return true
}
```

И ViewController:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "title"
content.body = "\(overdueProductsStringArray)"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "t", content: content, trigger: trigger)

center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в качестве триггера использовать дату срабатывания (в моем случае полученную из периода хранения).
Извините, пример выдрал из одного своего приложения, поэтому может все не очень красиво :)

```
    ...
    // Например срок закончится через 5 дней от текущего момента
    let periodInSeconds = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 
    var components = DateComponents()
    // Преобразование интервала в секундах в дату срабатывания уведомления в значениях компонентов
    components = intervalToComponents(perionInSeconds: periodInSeconds)

    // Создаем уведомления с использованием даты истечения срока
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.body = "Продукт испортился"
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: reminderNotificationId, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    ...


  // Преобразование интервала в секундах (от текущей даты) в дату срабатывания уведомления в значениях компонентов
  private func intervalToComponents(perionInSeconds: Int) -> DateComponents {
    // Текущая дата
    let date = NSDate() as Date
    // Нахождение даты срабатывания уведомления
    let notificationDate = date.addingTimeInterval(Double(perionInSeconds))
    // Извлечение из даты срабатывания элементов (день, час, минута) и помещение их в компоненты
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: notificationDate)
    return components
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: local notifications, если приложение выгружено из памяти, никак не отправить. Только remote notifications, через сервер. Используйте APNS.

[Update]
Не прав :) Выше правильно написали, локальные нотификации прекрасно работают даже если приложение выгружено из памяти, нужно просто создать триггер.

Comment: APNS + Firebase?

Comment: Да, APNS в связке с Вашим сервером, который будет генерить пуши.